# MobileServiceSQLiteStore Defining a table with a generic Type

Tags: c#, generics, types

I was wondering if there's a way to use a generic Type when you define a table?

The DefineTable method takes your model to define the local table on the mobile phone. The model type is specified using angular brackets. However I am looking to pass a Type object and use this to define the table, however, you cannot use a variable inside angular brackets.

Below are code samples and more explanation of what exactly I am looking for...

This is how it is currently being implemented:

```
public async Task Init()
{
    this.initialized = true;
    const string Path = "syncorder.db";
    var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(Path);

    store.DefineTable<Order>();
}
```

This is to get an idea of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
public async Task Init(Type tableType)
{
    this.initialized = true;
    const string Path = "syncorder.db";
    var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(Path);

    //This is what i would like to do, but cant since its not possible to put variables inside angular brackets
    store.DefineTable<tableType>();
}
```

I have also tried checking if it is possible to pass in the Type object as a parameter to the DefineTable method (since in some cases this is possible) but there is no overload allowing this.

```
   //This is not possible...
   store.DefineTable(tableType);
```

Anyhow all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out how to do this in case anyone runs into this issue below is the solution:

```
public Task Init(Type tableType)
{
    try
    {
        this.initialized = true;
        const string Path = "syncorder.db";
        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(Path);

        MethodInfo myDefineTable = RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeMethod(typeof(MobileServiceSQLiteStoreExtensions), "DefineTable", new Type[] { typeof(MobileServiceSQLiteStore) });
        myDefineTable = myDefineTable.MakeGenericMethod(tableType);
        myDefineTable.Invoke(null, new object[] { store });

    for the parameters to pass into the method
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.initialized = false;

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone... cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can just do the following:

```
public IMobileServiceSyncTable<T> Init<T>()
{
    var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(DatabaseName);
    store.DefineTable<T>();
    var Client = Client = new MobileServiceClient(SystemOptions.AzureStorage);
    Client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
    return Client.GetSyncTable<T>();
}
```